# Powershell split xml node and add in same file

Tags: xml, powershell

I am parsing the xml file and in particular node I have to split it first and then perfomr add operation in it and then insert the new node above it.

My XML file:

```
<Project Default="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="1.0">
<Items>
    <Resource Include="File\Scripts\Main.xml" />
    <Resource Include="File\Scripts\File101_102.xml" />
</Items>
</project>
```

Powershell:

```
[xml]$xdoc = Get-Content $path
$NodeInsertAfter=$xdoc.project.Items.Resource[0]
$StringtoSplit=$xdoc.project.Items.Resource[1]
$a=$StringtoSplit.Include.ToString().split('\')
$a=$StringtoSplit.Include.ToString().split('\')
$a
```

I have reached to read the node But how would I use the split function to increment the file number i.e. File102_103.xml

My Output must be:

```
<Project Default="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="1.0">
<Items>
    <Resource Include="File\Scripts\Main.xml" />
    <Resource Include="File\Scripts\File102_103.xml" />
    <Resource Include="File\Scripts\File101_102.xml" />
</Items>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `regex` to extract the two numbers:

```
$fileNumberRegex = '(\d+)_(\d+)'
$match = [regex]::Match($StringtoSplit.Include, $fileNumberRegex)
$StringtoSplit.Include -replace $fileNumberRegex, ('{0}_{1}' -f (1+$match.Groups[1].Value), (1+$match.Groups[2].Value))
```

Comment: thnaks but how I will save it after the first line(normally line added to below to upper line but I have to add upwards) like in output and so on for incremental file name.

Comment: Just clone the `$NodeInsertAfter` node using `Clone()`, then change the filename using my script above and finally append the node using the `AppendChild` function.